# Updating column in sqlserver based on values from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table column in sql server 2014 based on values in a different column from the same table. Here is a snippet of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [fruit] [varchar](50) NULL

INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (1, NULL, N'one')
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (2, NULL, N'apple')
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (3, NULL, N'banana')
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (4, NULL, N'orange')
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (5, NULL, N'two')
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (6, NULL, N'apple')
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (7, NULL, N'banana')

+----+--------+--------+
| id | number | fruit  |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | NULL   | one    |
|  2 | NULL   | apple  |
|  3 | NULL   | banana |
|  4 | NULL   | orange |
|  5 | NULL   | two    |
|  6 | NULL   | apple  |
|  7 | NULL   | banana |
+----+--------+--------+

+----+--------+--------+
| id | number | fruit  |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | one    | one    |
|  2 | one    | apple  |
|  3 | one    | banana |
|  4 | one    | orange |
|  5 | two    | two    |
|  6 | two    | apple  |
|  7 | two    | banana |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Basically I want to update the null columns in number with values from the fruit column, whenever a string appears that isn't 'apple, banana, orange' and I want that value to keep being entered until a new string appears in fruit. So the outcome should look like the second example.

I think I need to use a loop of some kind but I'm not really sure how to go about it, so far my attempt is

```
declare @i varchar
set @i = 'one'

while @i = 'one' or @i not in ('apple', 'banana', 'orange')
begin
update Table1
set number = @i

set @i = fruit

end
```

But I get an error when trying to set @i = fruit

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Storing data like that is a bad idea. Poorly normalized, data redundancy, and also a high risk of data inconsistency... (If you really, really want to do it, either use a view, or a computed column, or perhaps handle it using triggers.)

Comment: As above, this is a poorly structured table system. Are you in a position to redesign it? Also, what is the purpose of inserting "one" and "two"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. +1 for including the ddl+dml for the sample data in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My intention isn't to store data in my table like this, in my actual table I just need to populate the second column and the excel spreadsheet of data I'm working from has trapped some of the values in the third column. So I'm basically looking to extract them and then clean the table up.
edit: the values 'one, two' are meaningless, they could be any value. But there will be a list of strings (which I will know the values of that I want to skip over, represented in this example by 'apple, banana, orange'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @tb as TABLE (    [id] [int] NULL,    [number] [varchar](50) NULL,    [fruit] [varchar](50) NULL)

INSERT @tb ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (1, NULL, N'one')
INSERT @tb ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (2, NULL, N'apple')
INSERT @tb ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (3, NULL, N'banana')
INSERT @tb ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (4, NULL, N'orange')
INSERT @tb ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (5, NULL, N'two')
INSERT @tb ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (6, NULL, N'apple')
INSERT @tb ([id], [number], [fruit]) VALUES (7, NULL, N'banana')

select * from @tb

declare @count int = (select COUNT(*) from @tb)
declare @cursor int = 1
declare @updateValue as nvarchar(10)

While @cursor <= @count
BEGIN
set @updateValue = ISNULL((select fruit from @tb where id = @cursor and fruit not in ('apple', 'banana', 'orange')),@updateValue);
update @tb set number = @updateValue where id = @cursor
set @cursor = @cursor + 1;
END

select * from @tb
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE dbo.Table1
SET number = t.fruit
FROM (SELECT t1.id, t2.fruit    
      FROM (SELECT id, 
                   MAX(CASE WHEN fruit NOT IN ('apple','banana','orange') 
                            THEN id ELSE 0 END)
                   OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS i
           FROM dbo.Table1) t1
      INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 t2 ON t2.id = t1.i) t
WHERE t.id = dbo.Table1.id;
```

The `MAX` expression uses newer (Sql Server 2012) [windowing functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to pair an id with the id of the closest preceding row not containing `'apple'`, `'banana'`, or `'orange'`, then it just joins to the original table and does the update.