# Removing duplicates from one column only

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I would have something like this. Its the outcome a query into two tables.

```
+------------------+------------------------------------+
| character_name   | title                              |
+------------------+------------------------------------+
| derp             | a                                  |
| derp             | b                                  |
| derp             | c                                  | 
| herp             | a                                  |
| herp             | b                                  |
| herp             | c                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

and I want this

```
+------------------+------------------------------------+
| character_name   | title                              |
+------------------+------------------------------------+
| derp             | a                                  |
|                  | b                                  |
|                  | c                                  | 
| herp             | a                                  |
|                  | b                                  |
|                  | c                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can refer my answer here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125619/updating-column-in-sqlserver-based-on-values-from-another-column/35126041#35126041

Comment: I guess you are trying to say: remove duplicates When DISPLAY

Comment: I only want to remove the duplicates for the character_name column.

Comment: follow the link this will helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507887/eliminating-duplicate-values-based-on-only-one-column-of-the-table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507887/eliminating-duplicate-values-based-on-only-one-column-of-the-table Follow the link this will helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694871/remove-duplicate-values-of-only-one-column-value-from-all-the-available-columns

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you mean?

```
select case when i.rnk = 1 THEN i.character_name  ELSE '' END as NAME
, i.title
from(
    select *
    , row_number() over (partition by character_name order by title) as rnk
    from t1
) i
order by i.character_name
```

First name will get the value 1, which you show in the result, anything else you hide.

**Update - MySql version**:

```
SET @r_name:='';

select name, title FROM (
    select @r_name:=CASE WHEN @r_name = name THEN '' 
    ELSE name
    END AS name
    , @r_name:=name
    , title
    FROM
    t1
) t2
```

Comment: this query is for mysql?!

Comment: @ashkufaraz I hadn't paid attention to the tags, I've added an update, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with assist of a user variable.

SQL:

```
SET @last_name = '';
SELECT
    IF(switch_name, tbl2.character_name, '') character_name,
    tbl2.title
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        character_name, 
        title, 
        character_name != @last_name switch_name, 
        @last_name:=character_name 
    FROM
        tbl
    ) tbl2;
```

Result:

```
mysql> SELECT character_name, title FROM tbl;
+----------------+-------+
| character_name | title |
+----------------+-------+
| derp           | a     |
| derp           | b     |
| derp           | c     |
| herp           | a     |
| herp           | b     |
| herp           | c     |
+----------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @last_name = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT
    ->     IF(switch_name, tbl2.character_name, '') character_name,
    ->     tbl2.title
    -> FROM
    ->     (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         character_name,
    ->         title,
    ->         character_name != @last_name switch_name,
    ->         @last_name:=character_name
    ->     FROM
    ->         tbl
    ->     ) tbl2;
+----------------+-------+
| character_name | title |
+----------------+-------+
| derp           | a     |
|                | b     |
|                | c     |
| herp           | a     |
|                | b     |
|                | c     |
+----------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

it will work for your given table

```
   SELECT CASE  
    WHEN character_name ='derp' AND title ='a' THEN 'derp'
    WHEN character_name ='derp' AND title ='b' THEN ''
    WHEN character_name ='derp' AND title ='c' THEN ''
    WHEN character_name ='herp' AND title ='a' THEN 'herp'
    WHEN character_name ='herp' AND title ='b' THEN ''
    WHEN character_name ='herp' AND title ='c' THEN ''
    end as character_name,
    title
    from table_name;
```

NOTE : if your data is dynamic or not as shown above then you have to rewrite/optimize query to get your desired result.